# How to get the system-on-chip information (Samsung Exynos, Nvidia Tegra etc) in Android?

Tags: android

For example Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 N8000 is using Samsung Exynos 4, but the best I can get is `ARMv7 Processor rev 0 (v71)` from the `/proc/cpuinfo` file. Nothing useful in `System.getProperties()` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on how many information you want to get. A quick check on my S3LTE shows the actual CPU hardware as well:

```
shell@android:/proc $ cat cpuinfo
Processor      : ARMv7 Processor rev 0 (v7l)
(...)   
Hardware       : SMDK4x12
```

There you go: I've got an **SMDK4x12**

If you want to venture further, it is I'm afraid device (or platform) specific. You can check `sysfs`, and try to determine some other platform information from that. For example from the two commands below I can see I have an `exynos4-core` on an `s5pv210`*. Of course I already knew this, so I could only use this information to test their presence. On other platforms, like Qualcomms, Tegras and MTKs there are other signatures of the platform present in the `sysfs` you can search for.

```
$ ls /sys/devices/system
clocksource
cpu
exynos4-core

$ ls /sys/devices/platform | grep s5p 
s5pv210-uart.0
s5pv210-uart.1
s5pv210-uart.2
s5pv210-uart.3
```

* This is actually a red herring, the actual platform is S3C2440, but inside the kernel there are still remains of the s5pv210, which was used inside the original Samsung Galaxy S

Comment: Thanks! I see `SMDK4x12` in Galaxy Note 10.1 too. My Xperia, which has a `Qualcomm Snapdragon S1 MSM7227A`, has a value of `QCT MSM7x27a SURF`.